# How to properly embed a preview into EPS for use in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, thumbnails, preview, eps

I know that EPS is not the best format for MS Word. Unfortunately I'm forced to use MS Word and EPS is the format I have most figures in. I'd prefer to stay with EPS in case I make other LaTeX documents.

It looks like [MS Word can embed EPS for quality printing however it relies on a preview to show](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/graphics-file-types-word-can-use-HP005189346.aspx) while editing. I use R to produce figures using `postscript` command. This does not embed a preview into a file as can be seen with [epstool](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm) and it does not look like possible to embed it using R. So I assume that default image I see in MS Word is that generated by the Encapsulated PostScript graphics filter (Epsimp32.flt).

**Q:** Is there a way to embed a better *preview* into EPS so MS Word can make use of it? I know that my figures print just fine on PostScript enabled printer with proper drivers, but it looks just terrible on screen.

I tried that epstool with various settings without success. Though calling `gswin32.exe -r600 my.eps` does produce nicely looking image. I wonder if that import filter recreates its own preview.

**Update 12/20/2012:**

I should have written that I use MS Word 2007. I can see some unconclusive discussion on [Adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2002708) about issues with EPS import filter in that version of MS Word. Though they deal with PDF and I have no problem printing using PDF printer. However when I *Save as PDF* from MS Word it uses an ugly preview instead of vector data.